# What are some open source encoder-decoder libraries/binaries for ARM v8 and above?

Tags: arm, arm64

A basic search yielded me results for Capstone disassembler for ARM v8, can I get details on some open source encoders and decoders for ARM v8 and above?

Comment: Have you tried keystone?